# How to parse this html string data in Android?

Tags: android, html, parsing

Any one have idea how to parse this Html String value.

this one am tried

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xpp.nextText());
org.jsoup.nodes.Element element = doc.select("src").first();
Log.i("content:encoded is.", "content:encoded ==>"+ element);
```

this is html string

```
<p><img class="alignnone" title="Baby one" src="https://i0.wp.com/images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/17400000/Sweet-angel-sweety-babies-17465667-600-399.jpg" alt="Babies" width="600" height="399" />
</p> <p>Test of Baby one here</p> <p><img class="alignnone" title="Baby Two" src="https://i0.wp.com/www.tumblr18.com/t18/2013/10/Cute-pumpkin-baby.jpg" alt="" width="725" height="483" /></p> <p>Test of Baby two here this is important data of baby two</p> 
<p><img class="alignnone" title="Baby Three" src="https://i0.wp.com/i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01778/baby_1778233b.jpg" alt="" width="620" height="388" /></p> <p>Here Third baby details</p><br /> <a rel="nofollow" href="http://feeds.wordpress.com/1.0/gocomments/funnybtesting.wordpress.com/28/"><img alt="" border="0" src="http://feeds.wordpress.com/1.0/comments/funnybtesting.wordpress.com/28/" /></a> 

<img alt="" border="0" src="https://pixel.wp.com/b.gif?host=funnybtesting.wordpress.com&#038;blog=71336161&#038;post=28&#038;subd=funnybtesting&#038;ref=&#038;feed=1" width="1" height="1" />
```

`NOTE:` Am except output like this

```
 title="Baby one" 
 first images src="https://i0.wp.com/images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/17400000/Sweet-angel-sweety-babies-17465667-600-399.jpg"    
 String test = <p>Test of Baby one here</p>
```

second

```
 title="Baby two" 
 second image src="https://i0.wp.com/www.tumblr18.com/t18/2013/10/Cute-pumpkin-baby.jpg"
 String test = Test of Baby two here this is important data of baby two
```

third

```
 title="Baby three" 
 second image src="https://i0.wp.com/i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01778/baby_1778233b.jpg"
 String test = Here Third baby details.
```

Comment: use Jsoup for parsing html tags

Comment: How about jsoup? http://www.mkyong.com/java/jsoup-html-parser-hello-world-examples/

Comment: Did you try anything before posting here?

Comment: Hope this [link][1] can help .......


  [1]: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38227/simplifying-html-parsing

Comment: @Marius yes trying but am getting only first item.

Comment: Then show us what you accomplished so far, and we will help you. So far, it seems you just asked a question with no research.

Comment: You're simple selecting first element. You should select `Elements`, notice plural form, and loop trough them.

Comment: in the above @Aniruddha url am getting title and src image  fine, but un able to read `<p>Test of Baby one here</p> ` how to get this data. this is code am useing `Elements links = doc.select("img");
        for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element link : links) {       
         // get the value from href attribute
         Log.i("Title : ","src_title ==> " + link.attr("title"));
         Log.i("image : ","src_src ==> " + link.attr("src"));
         Log.i("text : ","src_test ==> " + link.attr("<p>"));       
        } `